# Unidad y departamento en un hospital

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-entre-palabras

En los hospitales de España, ¿es lo mismo una unidad y un departamento, o existe alguna diferencia entre ambos términos? De haberla, ¿me podrían dar un ejemplo donde se vea la diferenciación?

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A veces el concepto unidad/departamento se confunde en el lenguaje, ya que en algunos lugares de Iberoamérica se habla por ejemplo de unidad hospitalaria y dentro de ella se sigue hablando de la unidad de emergencias, de la unidad quirúrgica... En España, para los profesionales de la medicina, unidad/departamento, significan cosas distintas.

**Existen unidades y en cada unidad hay departamentos.**

Por ejemplo, en la unidad de Cirugía General, se encuentra el departamento o sección de colon, otro departamento o sección de páncreas...

***La unidad de enfermería es el conjunto de departamentos y recursos materiales relacionados con el personal de enfermería.***

La unidad de enfermería se encuentra formada por alguno de los siguientes departamentos;

- Jefe/a de enfermería.
- Coordinadora de Control de Infecciones.
- Coordinadora de enfermería.
- Quirófano, Recuperación y Esterilización.
- Áreas Críticas.
- Hospitalización.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Según lo que me explica, parece que una unidad comprende varios departamentos, aunque por la respuesta de Danielillo, parece que existe disparidad de criterios. Quizás depende del hospital.

Comment: Hola @kanachan, espero que te encuentres bien. Mi respuesta esta contrastada con un familiar que es médico en un hospital en la unidad de "Urología". Así en la unidad de Urología se puede encontrar el departamento o sección de "cáncer de próstata", "Litiasis (cálculos o piedras en el riñón), departamento o sección de "Cáncer de Vejiga", "Cáncer de Riñón"... Lo que ocurre es que hay que diferenciar entre hospitales pequeños y más grandes. Así en los hospitales pequeños, en la "Unidad de Urología" no existen distintos departamentos y son ellos los que hacen y llevan todo.

Comment: En los hospitales más grandes las unidades suelen estar divididas en departamentos o secciones, cuanto más grandes, más especialidades y divisiones habrá. Según me ha comentado en los hospitales grandes de las grandes ciudades los criterios y divisiones de unidades y departamentos, llamados estos también secciones, suelen ser los mismos. ¡Saludos!

Comment: ¡Hola, @Diego! Muchas gracias por la explicación que ha añadido y por consultar a su familiar, se lo agradezco mucho. Me ha sido de gran ayuda para comprender mejor la división entre unidades y departamentos. ¡Saludos!

Comment: @kanachan ¡Gracias a ti! Me alegro que te haya servido de ayuda. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

*Departamento* es el término genérico que puede englobar varias *unidades*.

> La **Unidad** de Hematología y Oncología Pediátrica de HM Hospitales, pertenece a HM CIOCC y está ubicada en el Hospital Universitario HM Montepríncipe por su relación con el **Departamento** de Pediatría y sus distintas especialidades.

<sub>*Fuente [Hospital Universitario Puerta del Sur](https://www.hmpuertadelsur.com/especialidades/unidades-medicas/oncologos-pediatricos)*</sub>

En el ejemplo del enlace, la *unidad* referida está ubicada en este hospital por pertenecer al *departamento* de pediatría del mismo, de lo que se deduce que en ese mismo *departamento* hay otras varias *unidades* relacionadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Según el ejemplo, parece que un departamento puede englobar varias unidades, aunque por la respuesta de Diego, parece que existe disparidad de criterios. Quizás depende del hospital.

Comment: Bueno, mi respuesta tiene un enlace que avala lo respondido.